# Try to specify file permissions using Output Channels in syslog

Tags: linux, file-permissions, rsyslog

I'm trying to use syslog with output channels to create some log files and I need them to have specific owners and permissions

Within the /etc/rsyslog I'm writing the following:

```
$umask 0027
$FileGroup the-mothers-of-invention

$outchannel rotate1,/path/mylog.log, 10000000,/path/my-rotate-script.sh /path mylog 99 .log 10000000

$template myTemplate,"%timegenerated:1:23:date-rfc3339%+%timegenerated:28:36:date-rfc3339% %syslogpriority-text:1:2:uppercase%hostname%:%msg%\n"


if $app-name == 'MYAPP' then {
    *.*  :omfile:$rotate1;myTemplate
    stop
    }
```

With this configuration, I see the first *mylog.log* file is created with permission *640* and groupID *the-mothers-of-invention*, but after reaching the 10mb, the script is correctly executed (I used the mv command) and I see the file mylog__.log is created and it inherits the owner and permissions from the original *mylog.log* file (so far, everything ok), **but**, when the new *mylog.log* file is automatically created by syslog, it is created with the default owner (root:root) and permissions (644).

I've been reading a lot of information & manuals (the rsyslog ones), but I don't see any information on combining the permissions change and the output channels.

Any guess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$FileCreateMode` parameter allows to specify the creation mode with which rsyslogd creates new files. It lets rsyslog create files with read and write access only for the users it runs under.

First, remove any restrictions for rsyslog:

```
$umask 0000
```

Then you can set the creation mode:

```
$FileCreateMode 0600
*.* /var/log/file-with-0600
$FileCreateMode 0644
*.* /var/log/file-with-0644
```

---

If there is a listener who must bind to a network port below `1024`, `rsyslogd` always needs to start up as root.
For example, the UDP listener usually needs to listen to `514` and as such `rsyslogd` needs to start up as root.

This means if you have any listener as described above, you can't change the fileowner - atleast if you're creating a file with rsyslog.

If that's not the case, you can use the `$PrivDropToGroup` and/or `$PrivDropToUser` config params to specify a group and/or user that `rsyslogd` should drop to after initialization.

```
# These may require root privilege
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
```

Answer (score 2):

As eDonkey said, since I'm not using any UDP listener, I included the FileGroup and PrivDropToGroup before instantiating the outChannel, as this:

```
$umask 0000
$outchannel rotate1,/path/mylog.log, 10000000,/path/my-rotate-script.sh /path mylog 99 .log 10000000

$template myTemplate,"%timegenerated:1:23:date-rfc3339%+%timegenerated:28:36:date-rfc3339% %syslogpriority-text:1:2:uppercase%hostname%:%msg%\n"

if $app-name == 'MYAPP' then {
   $FileCreateMode 0640
   $FileGroup the-mothers-of-invention
   $PrivDropToGroup the-mothers-of-invention
   *.*  :omfile:$rotate1;myTemplate
   stop
}
```

Thanks a lot!